# Repetição no for equivalente a um segundo

Tags: python, for

Quanto seria o valor limite para um for ficar repetindo que se comparasse a um segundo? Por exemplo:

```
for x in range(0, 1000):
    print("1 segundo")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não tem como fazer essa previsão inclusive porque cada computador demorará um tempo completamente diferente, piora o fato de existir IO na operação. Você pode mandar o processo dormir por um segundo. Quase sempre você não quer fazer isto e não faz muito sentido a não ser para testes específicos ou algum problema muito nichado. Seria algo assim:

```
import time

time.sleep(1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/IO/Sleep.py).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.sleep) para executar uma iteração com um determinado tempo estimado.

```
import time

for i in range(0, 3):
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Hello World"
```

Esse trecho de código irá imprimir o `Hello World` 3 vezes, sendo que, cada iteração será executada após 1 segundo.

Answer (score 0):

Não tem pois isso depende do seu computador o que você pode fazer é, utilizando a biblioteca time com `import time` adicionar um `time.sleep(1)` ou calcular as diferenças em `time.clock()` para marcar tempo de execução e assim fazer o que deseja

Answer (score -1):

Para o seu caso pode se importar o 'time' que vai servir como cronometro

```
Ao invés de 

for x in range(0, 1000):
    print("1 segundo")


Nós podemos usar:

import time

for x in range(0, 1000):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("1 segundo")
```